# connect database to another computer

Tags: java, oracle, soap, jdbc

I have two computers on one network. I have entered the ip of another computer, it works fine in the browser, but when using this ip on java I found the database connected to my localhost database not from the other computer!

my code jdbc

```
  public Connection MakeConnect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:http://192.168.1.109:5560/isqlplus", "school",
            "sch"); // first : user(hr) second pass(hr) .!

   return connection ; // return connetion of database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JDBC connection string may be in a wrong format. You should provide this in the following way:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

Instead it looks you specified ISQLPLus link. I haven't tested it but my guts say me it is the reason. I think in your case it should be something like that:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.109/SERVICEorSID
```

And you have to find the service name by yourself. In a generic case it is a name of the database. By default it is usually set to ORCL but possibly you set it to another name.

Make sure you read a following document: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC

Answer (score 0):

If the connection succeeds without error and if this `192.168.1.109` ip address is not of your local machine then it must connect to some other machine.

What made you think it's connecting to the local DB instance?

Comment: i have tested many quries and found all getting data from my old or local database not from anouther computer !

Comment: Then clean and compile the code. Since you have hard coded the URL it may occur if some old compiled class is being used.

Comment: i have cleaned all my projects but still reading from old database

Answer (score 0):

Check firewall settings of the other computer. Sometimes it may not allows for the external connections

Comment: If OP is getting the results connection is succeeding.

Comment: but if the connection filed should give me an error , not giving my old database >

Comment: do you use MySQL with PHP myadmin ??

Comment: See the discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859491/how-to-connect-to-oracle-10g-from-remote-client

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow a specific client ip-address (for example: 192.168.1.4) to access the mysql database running on a server, you should execute the following command on the server that is running the mysql database.

```
    $ mysql -u root -p
    Enter password:
    mysql> use mysql
    mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'192.168.1.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password'; 
    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also, update firewall rules to make sure port# 3306 is open on the server that is running the mysql database.

Comment: i'm using orcle , i should install tomcat to anouther computer ?